# How do you save and load mixed data types?

Tags: android, save

I have couple of dozen pieces of data that I need to save and load on start of the application.  They are int, String, long , array data types.  I am confused that there seems to be so many ways to do this.  It seems each variation has different methods. The some of the data gets modified while the app runs.  Lets say I have the following

```
  int WifiOn="1";
  private long Lasttime="00/00/00";
  private String UserId="12345678";
  private String URLResource[]= {"A","B","C");
  //I open file...
  FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("userPref.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

what do I do next with my four data types to save them out to internal storage?
And then what is the method to load them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the `SharedPreference`s and `SQLite databases` that Dheeresh Singh mentions you can also use [`Serialization`](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) since you only use simple datatypes.

How to write data to a file with serialization:

```
//create an ObjectOutputStream around your (file) OutputStream
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
//The OOS has methods like writeFloat(), writeInt() etc.
oos.writeInt(myInt);
oos.writeInt(myOtherInt);
//You can also write objects that implements Serializable:
oos.writeObject(myIntArray);
//Finally close the stream:
oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

How to read data from a file with serialization:

```
//Create an ObjectInputStream around your (file) InputStream
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
//This stream has read-methods corresponding to the write-methods in the OOS, the objects are read in the order they were written:
myInt = ois.readInt();
myOtherInt = ois.readInt();
//The readObject() returns an Object, but you know it is the same type that you wrote, so just cast it and ignore any warnings:
myIntArray = (int[]) ois.readObject();
//As always, close the stream:
ois.close();
```

On a side note, consider wrapping your In/OutStream in a BufferedInput/OutputStream to squeeze out some extra read/write performance.

Comment: I'm new to Java, but understand Buffered I/O what do you mean by wrapping the I/O in a Buffered I/O stream? Additionally in your example I assume I also have to flush 'fos' (from my opening the stream) and close it?

Comment: You would do this: `BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);` to get a buffered stream. This reduces the amount of writes that has to be done to the underlying system and thus improving the write speed. The same goes for reading.

Comment: 'flushing' the stream means that any data left that has not yet been written (which can be the case with streams) is written out, so it is usually a good practise to do so before closing the stream, it is only possible on OutputStreams. When you are done with a stream you 'close' it, this means that it can close any connections and release resources that it is holding on to.

Comment: Looking at how I use the file streams and closing of them is this correct usage?                                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dirname + "userPrefs.dat"); 
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeInt(autoWifiStart);
oos.writeInt(airPlaneState);
//You can also write objects that implements Serializable:
oos.writeObject(URLResource);  //an array
//Finally close the stream(s):
oos.flush();
oos.close(); 
fos.flush();
fos.close();

Comment: Is this with Buffered I/O the correct usage?                             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dirname + "userPrefs.dat"); 
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos); //to get a buffered stream  
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeInt(autoWifiStart);
oos.writeInt(airPlaneState);
oos.writeObject(URLResource);
//Finally close the streams:
oos.flush();
oos.close(); 
bos.flush();
bos.close();
fos.flush();
fos.close();

Comment: Yes, that looks about right. (Usually the streams closes/flushes any underlying streams when calling close or flush, so you only need to call `oos.flush(); oos.close();` and that one will close the others. But there is nothing wrong by explicitly closing them all)

Answer (score 1):

id data is limited then can use `shared preference` and if data is much can use  `SQLite database`

```
 dozen pieces of data
```

Better to use SQLite database which is easy and efficient also for your need

see [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) for  how to use that

as per http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Your data storage options are the following:

- Shared Preferences

Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.

- Internal Storage

Store private data on the device memory.

- External Storage

Store public data on the shared external storage.

- SQLite Databases

Store structured data in a private database.

- Network Connection

Store data on the web with your own network server.

Answer (score 1):

if all the data is formatted the exact same way, you should probably use `JSON`, in a function you can create the objects and then write them into your file.

```
public bool writeToFile(int wifiOn, long lastTime, String userId, String [] urlResources) {
   JSONObject toStore = new JSONObject();
   FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("userPref.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

   toStore.put("wifiOn", wifiOn);
   toStore.put("lastTime", lastTime);
   toStore.put("userId", userId);
   toStore.put("urlResources", urlResources);

   try {
       fos.write(toStore.toString().getBytes());
       fos.close();
       return true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: putInt doesnt seem to be a Json attribute. Is optInt as in     toStore.optInt("autoWifiStart", autoWifiStart); Valid? Additionally I cant find the correct syntax for  toStore.put("URLResource", URLResource); this is an array of strings. JSON seems promising.